# How to include highcharts exporting module when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, highcharts

Instead of `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

How can I add it as a dependency when using webpack? Is it available under some module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the module:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

exporting(Highcharts);
```

or use require:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
require("highcharts/modules/exporting")(Highcharts);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tepuf4?file=index.js

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm

Comment: Is this just based on your understanding of how highchart's structures it's modules? Or where can I find out more about this structure?

Comment: This gives me an error of `Uncaught TypeError: exporting_1.default is not a function`?

Comment: Hi @Chris Stryczynski, I have added to my answer a link to documentation and a live example.